# How to boot from bootable usb, locked down computer

Tags: windows-10, boot, bitlocker

I have a bootable usb drive that i cannot boot from. the laptop that I am using is quite locked down, I do not have administrator privileges, USB drives in the OS is blocked (group policy), Shift-restart dosnt work, Unknown bios password. the main C: drive is also encrypted with bitlocker. I can access an Admin cmd by forcing shutdown in boot 3 times to get into "your PC did not start correctly" and selecting CMD, i can access the bcd but when I edit it so that it SHOULD boot of of my USB it dosnt. not a clue why. the USB i am trying to boot into is Kali Linux live (so that i can crack the bitlocker password, I forgot it), its also a laptop, fairly new one also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New machines with Windows 10 have secure boot enabled to prevent people from starting the computer by USB. If you do not have the administrator id or credentials, you will not be able to start it with USB of any kind except the Windows vendor recovery USB.

Comment: Is there any way to crack the bitlocker recovery key or run a capable program that could extract a hash or image the disk in the recovery environment? the disk only unlocks on boot, and is locked while in the recovery environment. i tried running a BCD editor program in the recovery environment because i couldnt be bothered to learn how it works but that just came up with an error, "cannot run in win32 mode"

Comment: I do not think so as the BIOS is secured and if bit-lockered, really secure.

Comment: You state:  "I do not have administrator privileges, USB drives in the OS is blocked (group policy)". Is this your PC, or one from a school or employer? If it's a corporate PC, get IT to help. Consider the consequences of damaging or hacking someone else's property.

Comment: DrMoishe it is a old buisness pc that they let me take home after they went bankrupt